# What is そういう referring to in this dialogue?

Tags: scope

> A：「この本　借りてくよ。」
>   B：「あっ　学校の本は持ち出し禁止です。」
>   A：「じゃあ　黙っといてよ。」
>   B：「規則ですから　**そういう**わけには。」

---

In this exchange, when B says「そういうわけには。」, what does そういう refer to? Is she saying that she cannot keep quiet about A borrowing books, or more simply that A cannot borrow books? Is the scope of that phrase just the line immediately before or is it the situation as a whole?

Also, just so I'm clear, わけには is short for わけにはいかない, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think B is saying that Because it's the rules, they can't do it like that (stay silent). Although I mostly base it on [examples](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91%E3%81%AB%22). And yes, in this case わけには is definitelly short from of わけにはいかない and そういう refers to the proposed "solution".

Answer (score 0):

A very frequent usage of わけにはいかない is for something you can't do for moral reasons.
So I'd translate the last question as : It's the rule, so I'd never do such a thing/what you say (and stay silent about you taking out that book).